# Problema con generadores en javascript

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, traducción

En Python tenía este código para calcular pi:

```
import os
color = lambda: os.system('COLOR f0')
color()
def otravez():
    def calcPi(limit):
            q, r, t, k, n, l = 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3
            decimal = limit
            counter = 0
            while counter != decimal + 1:
                    if 4 * q + r - t < n * t:
                            yield n
                            if counter == 0:
                                    yield '.'
                            if decimal == counter:
                                    print('')
                                    break
                            counter += 1
                            nr = 10 * (r - n * t)
                            n = ((10 * (3 * q + r)) // t) - 10 * n
                            q *= 10
                            r = nr
                    else:
                            nr = (2 * q + r) * l
                            nn = (q * (7 * k) + 2 + (r * l)) // (t * l)
                            q *= k
                            t *= l
                            l += 2
                            k += 1
                            n = nn
                            r = nr
    def main():
            pi_digits = calcPi(int(input("Dime el número de cifras que quieres conseguir de pi a continuación:  ")))
            for d in pi_digits:
                    print(d, end='', flush=True)
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
    print("¿Quieres calcular más dígitos?")
    if input("Si es así escribe la palabra SI:  ") == "SI":
        clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
        clear()
        otravez()
otravez()
```

Pero al intentar pasarlo a javascript no funciona:

```html
<html>
  <head>
 <div id="Pi"></div>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Pi</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function* calcPi(limit){
   var q = 1;
   var r = 0;
   var t = 1;
   var k = 1;
   var n = 3;
   var l = 3;
   var nr = 0;
   var nn = 0;
   var decimal = limit;
   var counter = 0;
   
   while (counter != decimal + 1) {
    if (4 * q + r - t < n * t) {
     yield n;
     if (counter == 0) {
      yield '.';
     };
     if (decimal == counter) {
         break;
     };
     counter += 1;
     nr = 10 * (r - n * t);
     n = Math.floor((10 * (3 * q + r)) / t) - 10 * n;
     q *= 10;
     r = nr;
    } else {
       nr = (2 * q + r) * l;
       nn = Math.floor((q * (7 * k) + 2 + (r * l)) / (t * l));
       q *= k;
       t *= l;
       l += 2;
       k += 1;
       n = nn;
       r = nr;
    };
   };
  };
  var pi_digits = calcPi(parseInt(prompt("Dime el número de cifras que quieres conseguir de pi a continuación:  ")));
  for (var number in pi_digits) {
   document.getElementById('Pi').innerHTML += number;
  };
 </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Creo que es un problema con iteradores pero no sé como arreglarlo. Me sería muy util que alguien lo averiguara.
Gracias.

Comment: porque no usas "Math.PI" con esto ya obtendrias el valor de "PI" y para el numero de cifras usa "toFixed(n)"..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/PI

Comment: si estoy haciendo un código es porque quiero que el ordenador lo calcule, no poner un toFixed... has encontrado alguna solucion? estoy desesperado y no se que estoy haciendo mal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La funciones generadores retornan un iterador [funciones_iteradoras](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/function*) lo estabas invocando incorrectamente, le realice algunos ajustes a tú codigo, puedes verificar que el resultado sea el esperado.
Espero te sirva

```html
  <html>
  <head>
<div id="Pi"></div>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Pi</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function* calcPi(limit){
  var q = 1;
  var r = 0;
  var t = 1;
  var k = 1;
  var n = 3;
  var l = 3;
  var nr = 0;
  var nn = 0;
  var decimal = limit;
  var counter = 0;
  
  while (counter != decimal + 1) {
   if (4 * q + r - t < n * t) {
    yield n;
    if (counter == 0) {
     yield '.';
    };
    if (decimal == counter) {
        break;
    };
    counter += 1;
    nr = 10 * (r - n * t);
    n = Math.floor((10 * (3 * q + r)) / t) - 10 * n;
    q *= 10;
    r = nr;
   } else {
      nr = (2 * q + r) * l;
      nn = Math.floor((q * (7 * k) + 2 + (r * l)) / (t * l));
      q *= k;
      t *= l;
      l += 2;
      k += 1;
      n = nn;
      r = nr;
   };
  };
 };
 var numeroCifras = parseInt(prompt("Dime el número de cifras que quieres conseguir de pi a continuación:  "));

 for (let val of calcPi(parseInt(numeroCifras))) {
     document.getElementById('Pi').innerHTML += val;
 }
 
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: que rabia me da que no funcionase por el var number *in* pi_digits... Si tan solo hubiese puesto *of*  desde el principio...